# Linux Kernel Module program to obtain domain name from IP

Tags: c, linux, kernel, nslookup

I have a requirement to obtain the domain name from the destination IP from an outgoing packet. I am successful in capturing and obtaining the destination IP  packets using the `netfilter` hook as shown below.

```
unsigned int hook_func_out(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff * skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*)) 
{

    ofs = 20;   // Set theoffset to skip over the IP header.

    {   
            struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);  
            struct udphdr *udp_header;  
            struct tcphdr * tcp_header;

        //Ican obtain the destination IP address of the packet 
        //like this
        unsigned int dest_ip = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;

        //or like this          
        char pkt_tbuf[16];          
        snprintf(pkt_tbuf, 16, "%pI4", &ip_header->daddr);

        //here I need to obtain the domain name of the obtained destination address
    }
}
```

However, I have no idea on how to use that IP to obtain the domain name of the obtained IP.

I tried many sources (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=linux+kernel+programming+domain+name+from+IP+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) but did find any related information on the subject and will be really grateful if you experts would provide any sample code/ references to perform this task :)

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to do a *reverse DNS lookup*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kernel space, You can use `DNS Resolver Module` to query DNS from kernel space. 
Check the documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/dns_resolver.txt)

Enable and compile the module

```
The module should be enabled by turning on the kernel configuration options:

CONFIG_DNS_RESOLVER - tristate "DNS Resolver support"
```

Modify `/etc/request-key.conf` file as mentioned in document

Include dns_resolver.h

```
 #include <linux/dns_resolver.h>
```

Use dns_query function to query. Use `PTR` or `CNAME` as type to perform reverse DNS lookups

```
int dns_query(const char *type, const char *name, size_t namelen,
       const char *options, char **_result, time_t *_expiry);
```